# Issue with filtering of JSON nodes with JsonPath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have JSON with such structure:

```
{
    "stores": {
        "store1_id": {
            "books": {
                "book1_ISBN": {
                    "category": "reference",
                    "author": "Nigel Rees",
                    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                    "price": "8.95"
                },
                "book2_ISBN": {
                    "category": "fiction",
                    "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                    "title": "Sword of Honour",
                    "price": "12.99"
                }
            }
        },
        "store2_id": {
            "books": {
                "book3_ISBN": {
                    "category": "fiction",
                    "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                    "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                    "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                    "price": "22.99"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I parse it with [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath). I try to get all books with fiction category using such expression:

```
$[?(@.stores.*.books)].stores.*.books[?(@.*.category=="reference")]
```

but I get empty result, although according equal operator documentation I expect that I will receive "Sayings of the Century" book node:

```
"book1_ISBN": {
    "category": "reference",
    "author": "Nigel Rees",
    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
    "price": "8.95"
}
```

Interesting, that's when I use this expression without equals operator:

```
$[?(@.stores.*.books)].stores.*.books[?(@.*.category)]
```

I get all three books in result. Why my expression with equal operator don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your expressions here:
http://jsonpath.com/?
and they don't work, both of them, with filter and without filter.

I do not understand why you first filter these elements: (@.stores.*.books)

Anyway if you just want to filter all the books with category "fiction", this is simpler:

```
$..[?(@.category=="fiction")]
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I tested my expressions here: http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ and expression without equals operator works there, strange.. Anyway, I try your one and it return correct result (two nodes), thanks, but I see result don't contain ISBN keys - how can I get it too?

Comment: it does... this is what I see:<br> [
   {
      "category" : "fiction",
      "author" : "Evelyn Waugh",
      "title" : "Sword of Honour",
      "price" : "12.99"
   },
   {
      "category" : "fiction",
      "author" : "J. R. R. Tolkien",
      "title" : "The Lord of the Rings",
      "isbn" : "0-395-19395-8",
      "price" : "22.99"
   }
]

Comment: I mean the keys under "books" node, for instance "book2_ISBN", "book3_ISBN"

Comment: mmmh, I am afraid you need the parent operator which is not implemented in jsonPath: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations!